# Convert JSON lines to JSON array using jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, jsonlines

Firstly, I'm new to `jq`, like 1 day new, I'm also new to JSON, I'm an SQL guy so I'm learning fast but can't get my head around this ... so please bear with me.

I'm running Windows, using jq v1.5 on PowerShell.

I have multiple JSON files downloaded and they look like this:

```json
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Forward","UseCase":"Forward","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"EUR","ExpiryDate":"2018-01-01","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Contract for Difference (CFD)","DeliveryType":"CASH","BaseProduct":"AGRI","TransactionType":"FUTR","FinalPriceType":"ARGM","ReferenceRate":"10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN","SubProduct":"GROS","AdditionalSubProduct":"FWHT"},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZX27M86B860","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Agriculture","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Forward AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20180101","ShortName":"NA/Fwd AGRI FWHT EUR 20180101","ClassificationType":"JTAXCC"}}
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Swap","UseCase":"Basis_Swap","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"SOS","ExpiryDate":"2208-12-10","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Total Return","DeliveryType":"OPTL","TransactionType":"ORIT","FinalPriceType":"IHSM","ReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-MONTHLY INDEX S. TEXAS (TETCO)-GAS DAILY PRICE GUIDE","OtherReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-MONTHLY INDEX W. LOUISIANA (TETCO)-GAS DAILY PRICE GUIDE","BaseProduct":"OTHR","OtherBaseProduct":"OTHR","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","OtherSubProduct":"","OtherAdditionalSubProduct":""},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZBBH1XR9GV6","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Swap Basis_Swap OTHR   OTHR   SOS 22081210","ShortName":"NA/Swap OTHR   SOS 22081210","ClassificationType":"STQTXE"}}
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Swap","UseCase":"Multi_Exotic_Swap","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"LRD","ExpiryDate":"2200-01-31","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Contract for Difference (CFD)","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"TAPO","FinalPriceType":"EXOF","UnderlyingInstrumentIndex":["BCOMF6","BCOMNG3"]},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ286HJVY4Q2","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","BaseProduct":"MCEX","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","FullName":"Commodities Multi_Exotic_Swap MCEX LRD 22000131","ShortName":"NA/Swap MCEX LRD 22000131","ClassificationType":"STQCXC"}}
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Option","UseCase":"Option","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"TND","ExpiryDate":"2209-10-18","OptionType":"OPTL","OptionExerciseStyle":"AMER","ValuationMethodorTrigger":"Asian","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"OTHR","FinalPriceType":"IHSM","ReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-NGPL (NICOR, NIPSCO, PGLC CITYGATE), NBPL-NICOR-ICE/10X MONTHLY","BaseProduct":"OTHR","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":""},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ2TK5CWL9Y4","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Other","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Option OTHR   TND 22091018","ShortName":"NA/O OTHR  OPTL TND 22091018","ClassificationType":"HTMHAC"}}
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Option","UseCase":"Multi_Exotic_Option","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"SOS","ExpiryDate":"2209-10-18","UnderlyingInstrumentIndex":["BCOMSI2","BCOMPR3T"],"OptionType":"CALL","OptionExerciseStyle":"AMER","ValuationMethodorTrigger":"Other Path Dependent","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"ORIT","FinalPriceType":"BLTC"},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ82L36B6225","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","BaseProduct":"MCEX","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","FullName":"Commodities Multi_Exotic_Option MCEX SOS 22091018","ShortName":"NA/O MCEX Call SOS 22091018","ClassificationType":"HTQBPC"}}
```

The files can be upwards of 1 GB in size.

For me to use these effectively, I need to turn the JSON lines into JSON Arrays, wrapping the file, prepending "[" and appending "]" and for each line separate with a comma (,).

Making the file look like this (in theory):

```json
[
{
"Header": {
  "AssetClass": "Commodities",
  "InstrumentType": "Swap",
  "UseCase": "Basis_Swap",
  "Level": "InstRefDataReporting"
},
"Attributes": {
  "NotionalCurrency": "EUR",
  "ExpiryDate": "2017-08-31",
  "ReturnorPayoutTrigger": "Contract for Difference (CFD)",
  "DeliveryType": "CASH",
  "BaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "OtherBaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "TransactionType": "FUTR",
  "FinalPriceType": "ARGM",
  "ReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "OtherReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "SubProduct": "GROS",
  "AdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT",
  "OtherSubProduct": "GROS",
  "OtherAdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT"
},
"ISIN": {
  "ISIN": "EZ68CZDRFYY7",
  "Status": "New"
},
"TemplateVersion": 1,
"Derived": {
  "CommodityDerivativeIndicator": "TRUE",
  "UnderlyingAssetType": "Multi Commodity",
  "IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier": "NA",
  "PriceMultiplier": 1,
  "FullName": "Commodities Swap Basis_Swap AGRI GROS FWHT AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ShortName": "NA/Swap AGRI FWHT FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ClassificationType": "STQCXC"
  }
},
{
"Header": {
  "AssetClass": "Commodities",
  "InstrumentType": "Swap",
  "UseCase": "Basis_Swap",
  "Level": "InstRefDataReporting"
},
"Attributes": {
  "NotionalCurrency": "EUR",
  "ExpiryDate": "2017-08-31",
  "ReturnorPayoutTrigger": "Contract for Difference (CFD)",
  "DeliveryType": "CASH",
  "BaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "OtherBaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "TransactionType": "FUTR",
  "FinalPriceType": "ARGM",
  "ReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "OtherReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "SubProduct": "GROS",
  "AdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT",
  "OtherSubProduct": "GROS",
  "OtherAdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT"
},
"ISIN": {
  "ISIN": "EZ68CZDRFYY7",
  "Status": "New"
},
"TemplateVersion": 1,
"Derived": {
  "CommodityDerivativeIndicator": "TRUE",
  "UnderlyingAssetType": "Multi Commodity",
  "IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier": "NA",
  "PriceMultiplier": 1,
  "FullName": "Commodities Swap Basis_Swap AGRI GROS FWHT AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ShortName": "NA/Swap AGRI FWHT FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ClassificationType": "STQCXC"
}
}
]
```

So I've found jq and from my understanding i can run this

```
jq --slurp 'map(select(. >= 2))' Inputfile.json > OutputFile.json
```

This works but when running files larger than 200 MB i get "system out out of memory" error (if i use ISE) and if i use standard Powershell or CMD it takes ages. minutes (5+)

If i take `--slurp` out of the command, it works, it's quicker but the result looks like this:

```json
[
{
"Header": {
  "AssetClass": "Commodities",
  "InstrumentType": "Swap",
  "UseCase": "Basis_Swap",
  "Level": "InstRefDataReporting"
},
"Attributes": {
  "NotionalCurrency": "EUR",
  "ExpiryDate": "2017-08-31",
  "ReturnorPayoutTrigger": "Contract for Difference (CFD)",
  "DeliveryType": "CASH",
  "BaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "OtherBaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "TransactionType": "FUTR",
  "FinalPriceType": "ARGM",
  "ReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "OtherReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "SubProduct": "GROS",
  "AdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT",
  "OtherSubProduct": "GROS",
  "OtherAdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT"
},
"ISIN": {
  "ISIN": "EZ68CZDRFYY7",
  "Status": "New"
},
"TemplateVersion": 1,
"Derived": {
  "CommodityDerivativeIndicator": "TRUE",
  "UnderlyingAssetType": "Multi Commodity",
  "IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier": "NA",
  "PriceMultiplier": 1,
  "FullName": "Commodities Swap Basis_Swap AGRI GROS FWHT AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ShortName": "NA/Swap AGRI FWHT FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ClassificationType": "STQCXC"
  }
}]
[{
"Header": {
  "AssetClass": "Commodities",
  "InstrumentType": "Swap",
  "UseCase": "Basis_Swap",
  "Level": "InstRefDataReporting"
},
"Attributes": {
  "NotionalCurrency": "EUR",
  "ExpiryDate": "2017-08-31",
  "ReturnorPayoutTrigger": "Contract for Difference (CFD)",
  "DeliveryType": "CASH",
  "BaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "OtherBaseProduct": "AGRI",
  "TransactionType": "FUTR",
  "FinalPriceType": "ARGM",
  "ReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "OtherReferenceRate": "10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN",
  "SubProduct": "GROS",
  "AdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT",
  "OtherSubProduct": "GROS",
  "OtherAdditionalSubProduct": "FWHT"
},
"ISIN": {
  "ISIN": "EZ68CZDRFYY7",
  "Status": "New"
},
"TemplateVersion": 1,
"Derived": {
  "CommodityDerivativeIndicator": "TRUE",
  "UnderlyingAssetType": "Multi Commodity",
  "IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier": "NA",
  "PriceMultiplier": 1,
  "FullName": "Commodities Swap Basis_Swap AGRI GROS FWHT AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ShortName": "NA/Swap AGRI FWHT FWHT EUR 20170831",
  "ClassificationType": "STQCXC"
}
}
]
```

It creates an array for each line but the array is not comma separated, and thats not what I wanted.

So, how can I process large files, of multiple JSON lines, and create one file for the input file that is generated as a single array, comma separated, without using slurp?

I've read about inputs but not sure if that is relevant to what I need to do?

Comment: "Any ideas?" Yes, tell us what your actual goal is.  From what you say, this sounds like an xyproblem (http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you read my question, you will see I have stated what my goal is.... I need to turn the Json lines into arrays wrapping each file prepending,and appending with [] and separate each object with a ,

Comment: Yes, that is what your stated goal is, but why do you need to do that?

Comment: If it's 1GB in size then you should avoid making it into one huge JSON. There's a good reason it's saved .jsonl not .json — it's too big for memory. Write something in the programming that is consuming this that reads one line at a time, parses it, then does what ever it needs to do with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like `inputs` suffers from the same issue as slurp. I don't know how to accomplish this with `jq` on huge files, but `sed` can do it:

```
sed '1s/^/[/; $!s/$/,/; $s/$/]/' in.json > out.json
```

Output:

```json
[{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Forward","UseCase":"Forward","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"EUR","ExpiryDate":"2018-01-01","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Contract for Difference (CFD)","DeliveryType":"CASH","BaseProduct":"AGRI","TransactionType":"FUTR","FinalPriceType":"ARGM","ReferenceRate":"10PPM ULTRA LOW SULPHUR DIESEL-CARGOES CIF NWE/BASIS ARA-PLATTS EUROPEAN","SubProduct":"GROS","AdditionalSubProduct":"FWHT"},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZX27M86B860","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Agriculture","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Forward AGRI GROS FWHT EUR 20180101","ShortName":"NA/Fwd AGRI FWHT EUR 20180101","ClassificationType":"JTAXCC"}},
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Swap","UseCase":"Basis_Swap","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"SOS","ExpiryDate":"2208-12-10","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Total Return","DeliveryType":"OPTL","TransactionType":"ORIT","FinalPriceType":"IHSM","ReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-MONTHLY INDEX S. TEXAS (TETCO)-GAS DAILY PRICE GUIDE","OtherReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-MONTHLY INDEX W. LOUISIANA (TETCO)-GAS DAILY PRICE GUIDE","BaseProduct":"OTHR","OtherBaseProduct":"OTHR","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","OtherSubProduct":"","OtherAdditionalSubProduct":""},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZBBH1XR9GV6","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Swap Basis_Swap OTHR   OTHR   SOS 22081210","ShortName":"NA/Swap OTHR   SOS 22081210","ClassificationType":"STQTXE"}},
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Swap","UseCase":"Multi_Exotic_Swap","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"LRD","ExpiryDate":"2200-01-31","ReturnorPayoutTrigger":"Contract for Difference (CFD)","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"TAPO","FinalPriceType":"EXOF","UnderlyingInstrumentIndex":["BCOMF6","BCOMNG3"]},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ286HJVY4Q2","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","BaseProduct":"MCEX","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","FullName":"Commodities Multi_Exotic_Swap MCEX LRD 22000131","ShortName":"NA/Swap MCEX LRD 22000131","ClassificationType":"STQCXC"}},
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Option","UseCase":"Option","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"TND","ExpiryDate":"2209-10-18","OptionType":"OPTL","OptionExerciseStyle":"AMER","ValuationMethodorTrigger":"Asian","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"OTHR","FinalPriceType":"IHSM","ReferenceRate":"NATURAL GAS-NGPL (NICOR, NIPSCO, PGLC CITYGATE), NBPL-NICOR-ICE/10X MONTHLY","BaseProduct":"OTHR","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":""},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ2TK5CWL9Y4","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","UnderlyingAssetType":"Other","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"FullName":"Commodities Option OTHR   TND 22091018","ShortName":"NA/O OTHR  OPTL TND 22091018","ClassificationType":"HTMHAC"}},
{"Header":{"AssetClass":"Commodities","InstrumentType":"Option","UseCase":"Multi_Exotic_Option","Level":"InstRefDataReporting"},"Attributes":{"NotionalCurrency":"SOS","ExpiryDate":"2209-10-18","UnderlyingInstrumentIndex":["BCOMSI2","BCOMPR3T"],"OptionType":"CALL","OptionExerciseStyle":"AMER","ValuationMethodorTrigger":"Other Path Dependent","DeliveryType":"CASH","TransactionType":"ORIT","FinalPriceType":"BLTC"},"ISIN":{"ISIN":"EZ82L36B6225","Status":"New"},"TemplateVersion":1,"Derived":{"CommodityDerivativeIndicator":"TRUE","IssuerorOperatoroftheTradingVenueIdentifier":"NA","PriceMultiplier":1,"UnderlyingAssetType":"Multi Commodity","BaseProduct":"MCEX","SubProduct":"","AdditionalSubProduct":"","FullName":"Commodities Multi_Exotic_Option MCEX SOS 22091018","ShortName":"NA/O MCEX Call SOS 22091018","ClassificationType":"HTQBPC"}}]
```

#### Explanation

The sed script consists of three separate substitutions.  Here they are on  separate lines:

```sed
1  s/^/[/      # Insert a left bracket at the beginning of the first line
$! s/$/,/      # On all but the last line append a comma
$  s/$/]/      # Append a right bracket to the last line
```

Comment: This splits them across lines, which doesn't parse.

Comment: @rjurney: so json-files can't have new-lines in them?

Comment: they can if you escape them, but JSON Lines is one record per line. I dunno, they wouldn't parse for me. A JSON file should be able to have newlines but if you don't escape them some languages won't parse them?

Comment: @rjurney: right, I've never encountered this, sounds like a faulty parser. [According to the description on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types), whitespace is ignored unless found in strings.

Answer (score 67):

Maybe, I am late but this is what you are looking for!

```
jq --slurp '.' in.json > out.json
```

Comment: Great solution - very much prefer this over the accepted answer. Thanks! It's fast too!

Comment: This works. Use `jq -cs' to get the records on one line each, valid JSON Lines.

Comment: After this, get the eg second json line like: `jq -s '.[1]'`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe awk is easier on the eyes:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN{print "["} 
  length(last)>0 {print last ","} {last=$0}
  END {print last, "]"}
'
```

And for the record, here's a slurp-free solution using a version of jq with `input`:

```bash
jq -nr '"[", try (input|tojson, repeat(",\n\(input|tojson)")), "]"'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use one liner of node call:

```
$ cat input.ndjson | node -e 'const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin }); !async function () { let idx = 0; for await (const line of rl) { process.stdout.write((++idx === 1 ? "[" : "\n,") + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(line))); } process.stdout.write("]"); }()' | tee output.json | jq 'length'
16814
```

Explanation:

```
$ cat input.ndjson |      # pipe the ndjson input, can be a file or any stream
  node -e '
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin });
    !async function () {  // to be able to use await, this function has to be async, and then `!` is to be able call it right away;
      let idx = 0;
      for await (const line of rl) {
        process.stdout.write((++idx === 1 ? "[" : "\n,") + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(line)));
      }
      process.stdout.write("]");
    }()
  ' | tee output.json     # save the output json file
    | jq 'length'         # call jq to calculate a length, also validate it, to make sure it's a valid single json file, this optional
```

the `readline` of Node is a good one to read a stream by lines, and it's `asyncIterable`, can use (await ... of) to get each line, then call `JSON.parse` to make sure validate each line is a valid json, and then `JSON.stringify` to convert back to a minified JSON, on each line;

for sure you can change to a local `const arr = [];` and push each line's obj into t, and once JSON.stringify at the end, to get the most minified JSON,

but I like to get this almost minified format, that each line's obj is minified, but still keep the outer array line by line, so that I can easily get its total count by a `wc -l` count its lines

```
[{...minified line1obj with no spaces...}
,{...minified line2obj}
,{...minified line3obj}
,...
,{...minified lineNobj}]
```